# Can i getValue of 2 different classes in the same onDataChange function

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Hello i'm trying to get value of 2 different classes model in the same `DataSnapshot`?

Here is an example

```
 myDB.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {  
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                Model_1 m1 = dataSnapshot.getValue(model_1.class); // First class
                Model_2 m2 = dataSnapshot.getValue(model_2.class); // Second class
            }
 });
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Post your database structure.

Comment: Ok thanks @UmangBurman

Comment: I don't have it at the moment @AtifAbbAsi but i was trying to get an answer so i can carry on. Thanks anyways

Comment: Ok yes you can do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can i getValue of 2 different classes in the same onDataChange function

The answer is no! According to the official documentation of [DataSnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DataSnapshot) class:

> A DataSnapshot instance contains data from a Firebase Database location. Any time you read Database data, you receive the data as a DataSnapshot.

If you are using a model class, it means that you using the built-in `JSON-to-POJO` serializer/deserializer. So when you are using the following line of code:

```
Model_1 m1 = dataSnapshot.getValue(model_1.class);
```

It means that you deserialize the data from JSON straight back into a POJO class object. This also means that the type of the object can only be of a **single** type, which is of type `model_1`. It cannot also be of any other type, let's say `model_2`. It only can be of type `model_1`. So the `DataSnapshot` of a particular location can return an object of a single type.

Comment: No, there is not. You cannot to get two different types of object from a single location.

Comment: Do you think that my answer helped you?

Comment: Yes you r right. I've tried it and it's not working. So, you think i need to transfer all the objects in one class? Is that the only way?

Comment: Yes, you can do that but I'm not sure if it will help because I don't know the use-case of your app. But give it a try. Good luck with that!

Comment: Ok, but i think to avoid messing up everything i will use only one class. Thanks again